# generic type for ...args?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a function `time`

```js
const time = <T>(fn: (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>, ...args: any[]): Promise<T> => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => reject(`Error: ${fn.name} timed out`), ms)
    try {
      resolve(await fn.bind(thisArg)(...args))
    } catch(err) {
      reject(err)
    } finally {
      clearTimeout(timer)
    }
  })
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to avoid using `any` as the type of `...args`? Specifically because I want to relate the type of `...args` in the `fn` signature (`fn: (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>`) with the type of `...args` (the second parameter of the `time` function). These two `...args` are the same args, so it seems like they should be related by a generic. I thought of something like this:

```js
const time = <T, U>(fn: (...args: U[]) => Promise<T>, ...args: U[]): Promise<T>
```

but that seems wrong because the arguments will not all be of the same type. Rather, whatever the type is of `...args` in the `fn` signature, will also be the type of the second parameter `...args` of the `time` function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can do something like:

```
const time = <T, U extends unknown[]>(fn: (...args: U) => Promise<T>, ...args: U): Promise<T>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtX2wFsQAeAFQBp4BVeEADwxFWAGd40BrVHAd1QDaAXQB8ACkSoAXPDEA6BbADmrGdQCU8ALwj4ABRg5CWVqTIiqCuctU11Mg0ZNmRAKFdEQYsawwwZvjBYqEpUqABGMqjIhOEgMJo6+obGpnJwrDgQAG5efsgg6lQARAAWIBAQOMVUAIzqrkA)

> the arguments will not all be of the same type

The type of `...args` must indeed be an array/tuple, because it uses a rest operator.

But instead of typing as `U[]`, which indeed forces each individual argument to be of type `U`, we can simply type the whole array with a generic, provided that it is constrained to be an array: `U extends unknown[]` and now we can do `...args: U`

Comment: I'm pretty new to ts/js coming from a java background.  Can someone help me understand what the value of this is? Is this actually ensuring that each element in the array of `...args` will individually have the same types, in the same order (i.e. same param signature) everywhere `...args: U` is used?  For example I found this post looking to understand a similar signature.

`const wrapOnClickFunction = <T, U extends T[], V>(fn: (...args: U) => V) => {
    return async (...args: U): Promise<V> => {
        await this.props.dosomework();
        return fn(...args);
    };
};
`

Comment: Please feel free to open a new question with your specific details.